# Python Command to change from English to other language

Tags: python, scripting, text-editor

I am new to Blender Python Programming and tried to switch from English to Chinese using code.

However, I am probably not referencing the correct directory.

This is the code I tried:

```
import bpy

bpy.context.preferences.view.language.zh_CN.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set user interface language from Python you should use

```
import bpy

bpy.context.preferences.view.language = 'zh_CN'
```

[Link to the API docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.PreferencesView.html#bpy.types.PreferencesView.language)

Comment: Thank you! 
Now it works!

Comment: @DavidSchulz you can mark the answer as correct with the checkmark in the topleft of the post so it can help others in the future. :) cheers